# Display photos in dynamic folder asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to design a photos manager website application so i need to show all of photos in folders base on folder name and only use 1 aspx page.
i found many tutorail that can be work to display all photos in folder but i dont know how to display the photos in folder on choose the galery, for example: i have a folder photo on host server, in it have 2 sub folders that are: animal and flower. When i click on animal folder, all animal photos display on webpage and so on when click on flower folder, the flowers photos will be shown.

here my code i have:
ASPX page:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" BackColor="White"
            BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"   ForeColor="Black"
             Width="100%">
           <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                       <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                   <span class="style2">Image Gallary</span>
            </HeaderTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                      <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:ImageButton Width="105px" ID="Image1" runat="server"  BorderStyle="Solid" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/[foldername]/{0}") %>'
                      Height="94px"  />
                          <br />
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'  CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Name") %>'  runat="server" />
                      </ItemTemplate>
                          <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                          <ItemStyle BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                              VerticalAlign="Bottom" BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:DataList>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
private void ListImages()
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/images")); // it's will be animal if i click on animal and flower when i click on flower.
    FileInfo[] file = dir.GetFiles();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    foreach (FileInfo file2 in file)
    {
        if (file2.Extension == ".jpg" || file2.Extension == ".jpeg" || file2.Extension == ".gif" || file2.Extension == ".png")
        {
            list.Add(file2);
        }
    }
    DataList1.DataSource = list;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

i tried to add to list with full path as: list.add(dir.tostring()+file2.tostring()) but i can not call it from aspx page with <%# bind("Name") %>, the error is wrong property name! :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem in your code:

You need to create a property class with a `Name` property. Something like this:

```
public class ImageTest
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

then in your bindlist method:

```
private void ListImages()
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/images/Animal")); // it's will be animal if i click on animal and flower when i click on flower.
            FileInfo[] file = dir.GetFiles();
            // ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            List<ImageTest> list = new List<ImageTest>();
            foreach (FileInfo file2 in file)
            {
                if (file2.Extension == ".jpg" || file2.Extension == ".jpeg" || file2.Extension == ".gif" || file2.Extension == ".png")
                {
                    // list.Add(file2);
                    // list.Add(dir.ToString() + file2.ToString());
                    list.Add(new test()
                                 {
                                     Name = "http://localhost:58822/Images/Animal/" + file2.ToString() // where localhost path would be your site url
                                 });
                }
            }
            DataList1.DataSource = list;
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
```

Also you need to remove ~/[foldername]/{0}") %>' from your code and just keep the simple

```
 ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name") %>'
```

Comment: Thank you!!!i found my solution that custom bind the image.imageurl on item databound!! :D